# Email: addressing the users in CC

Tags: politeness, email

I am in a corporate setting, replying to an email from company's client. The email contains multiple participants in CC. I've never spoken to the client nor to anyone in CC. Is it normal to start my reply with:

> Hello "Name" and everyone in CC,

Or is there a better way to greet everyone and make it clear that I am aware that my communication will be read by all participants and not only by the receiver (TO field)?

Comment: I'm glad you want to participate, but this is an ettiquette question and not about the English language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In email, the abbreviation CC indicates those who are to receive a copy of a message addressed primarily to another (CC is the abbreviation of carbon copy).
>   [- Carbon Copy, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_copy)

Those in the 'cc:' list are sent the email as just a courtesy or 'carbon copy'. Since they aren't the 'proper' recipients to the email, they wouldn't normally be addressed directly in the email. Think of them as by-standers.

If you addressed them directly, they would be *direct recipients* of your communication, in which case they should properly be part of your 'to:' list.